# Convert a function view to a Class Based View Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to write a a Function-based View **(FBV)** as a Class-based View **(CBV)**, specifically a CreateView.

So far I have the Class based view created but the FBV I use takes a request and an ID so not sure how to handle that.

The FBV works fine but as a CBV I think its more complicated as I need to change the data being passed to the HTML

I think I shouldn't be using context but I don't know how to do it without

Thanks for any help

**FBV**

```
def pages(request, id):

   obj = programas.objects.get(id=id)
   script = obj.script
   script_eng = obj.script_eng
   zip_scripts = zip(script , script_eng)
   zip_scripts_eng = zip(script_eng , script)
   random_zip = list(zip(script , script_eng))
   random_ten = random.choices(random_zip)



   context = {'title': obj.title,
              'show_date': obj.show_date,
              'script' : obj.script,
              'script_eng': obj.script_eng,
              'description': obj.description,
              'description_eng': obj.description_eng,
              'show_id':obj.show_id,
              'url': obj.url,
              'random_ten': random_ten,
              'zip_scripts' : zip_scripts,
              'zip_scripts_eng ' : zip_scripts_eng ,
               }


   return render(request, 'rtves/pages.html', context)
```

**CBV**

```
class PagesContentView(ListView):
   model = programas
   context_object_name = "show_info"
   template_name = 'pages/index.html'

   def pages(request, id):

          obj = programas.objects.get(id=id)
          script = obj.script
          script_eng = obj.script_eng
          zip_scripts = zip(script , script_eng)
          zip_scripts_eng = zip(script_eng , script)
          random_zip = list(zip(script , script_eng))
          random_ten = random.choices(random_zip)



          context = {'title': obj.title,
                     'show_date': obj.show_date,
                     'script' : obj.script,
                     'script_eng': obj.script_eng,
                     'description': obj.description,
                     'description_eng': obj.description_eng,
                     'show_id':obj.show_id,
                     'url': obj.url,
                     'random_ten': random_ten,
                     'zip_scripts' : zip_scripts,
                     'zip_scripts_eng ' : zip_scripts_eng ,
                      }


          return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**URLS** working fine

```
urlpatterns = [
path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view()),
path('', views.IndexView.as_view()),    
path('pages/<int:id>/', PagesContentView.as_view()),
```

]

The Page loads fine but none of the data is returned from the Database.

**HTML**

```
{% if show_info %}

<h2>{{ title }}</h2>
<p>{{ description_eng | truncatewords_html:100 | safe }}</p>
    <p> Number of words: {{ script |wordcount }} </p>

{% endif %}


{% for rand in random_ten %}
    <p style="padding: 20px;text-align: left;color:#3d6cdd; line-height: 1.3;"> 
    {{ rand.0 |truncatewords:30 }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

If I use  **{{ show_info }}** or **{{ show_info.0 }}** I get a queryset returned of the first line of the function 'title': obj.title, but doesn't match the ID

Comment: Why do you pass all object attributes separately to the context? Why not pass an `'object': obj` and render it with `{{ obj.title }}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you here have is not a `ListView`, but a `DetailView`. You can implement this as:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
import random

class PagesContentView(DetailView):
    model = programas
    context_object_name = 'obj'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
    template_name = 'pages/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        zip_scripts = list(zip(self.object.script , self.object.script_eng))
        context.update(
            zip_scripts=zip_scripts
            zip_scripts_eng = zip(self.object.script_eng , self.object.script)
            random_ten=random.choices(zip_scripts)
        )
        return context
```

We here thus specify that the primary key in the URL path is `'id'`, not `'pk'`, and that we pass the object as `'obj'`.

In your template you can render this with:

```
<h2>{{ obj.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ obj.description_eng | truncatewords_html:100 | safe }}</p>
    <p> Number of words: {{ obj.script |wordcount }} </p>

{% endif %}


{% for rand in random_ten %}
    <p style="padding: 20px;text-align: left;color:#3d6cdd; line-height: 1.3;"> 
    {{ rand.0 |truncatewords:30 }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Note that `random_ten` will contain a single 2-tuple, not an iterable of 2-tuples. You probably are looking for the [**`random.sample`** function [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.sample) instead.

Models usually have singular names in `CamelCase`, so you might consider renaming your model to `Program`, not <s>`programmas`</s>. In URL paths, the primary key is usually named `pk`, not `id`. By doing that, you can remove the `pk_url_kwargs = 'id'` line.

Finally, as specified in the template, you usually do not pass every object attribute individually, but just pass an object, and render that object in the template.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, now I'm just getting Page not Found error, should I have to change the URL's file also for the DetailView

Comment: @JohnnyQ: no, normally a page not found means the URL itself is just wrong, otherwise it will give a 500 error.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the id field https://i.gyazo.com/4b6e7cce5470c68d839ee65363e6d9c7.png when I use the FBV it loads fine.

Comment: @johnnyQ: that is because there is no `programas` with `id=7`. Please inspect the database for valid ids.

Comment: How come it works them when I switch to the function view https://i.gyazo.com/56b8e148f6bc1894cfdb1784b1278dd4.png

Comment: @JohnnyQ: likely the fbv can not be the one you posted here, since that query would even have made it worse in the FBV: it would raise a 500. It furthermore does not make sense to render a detail page given no corresponding object exists.

Comment: @JohnnyQ: so there is a `programas` with `id=7` in your database? If there is no such object, then the `.get(id=id)` will raise a `DoesNotExists` error.

Comment: It works fine with the FBV but I wanted to convert it to a DetailView, but there must be some problem with the DetailView on my system as it can't find the URL, ListView works fine

Comment: @JohnnyQ: of course a listview works fine, since an empty list, is, well a list. But your FBV is not a listview, since you retrieve a single records with the `.get(..)`. A get should fail, by design, if it retrieves no, or multiple such records.

Comment: Yes, I know the FBV isn't a list view I'm using a different ListView on the models page. It's the DetailVIew I can't get to work.

Comment: Changed the id to the primary key and then connected them up and it worked. I think there was a conflict in the models as I had a field called id.